# How can I get the version of SSMS from VSIX

Tags: windows, visual-studio, ssms, vsix

I am developing an extention for SSMS using VSIX.
In this extension I need to know which version of SSMS I am running on.
What is the best way to get that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do it like this in my SSMS extension (for SSMS 16 and higher)

```
        var dte = GetServiceHelper(typeof(EnvDTE.DTE)) as EnvDTE.DTE;
        if (dte == null) return new Version(130, 0, 0, 0);
        if (dte.RegistryRoot.Contains("14.0"))
        {
            return new Version(140, 0, 0, 0);
        }
        return new Version(130, 0, 0, 0);
```

https://github.com/ErikEJ/SqlCeToolbox/blob/master/src/GUI/SSMSToolbox/Package/SqlCeToolboxPackage.cs#L67

Answer (score 0):

**dte.Version** returns **2015.0130** for SSMS 2016 and **2017.0140** for SSMS 17.